# How to setup proxy in Eclipse Integration Gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have a 407 error 'Proxy Authentication Required' (GET http://repo1.maven.org) when I try to build sample project in Eclipse. When run build from the command line it works. Environment variables are set in `.gradle` file and are available in Eclipse:

```
task printProperties << {
    println System.properties.'http.proxyHost' // prints my proxy host
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can setup last milestone release to use Gradle not-bundled with plugin: go to "Preferences" > "Gradle" > "Gradle Distribution" and select Gradle installation folder